# Regex - find string by excluding part of it

Tags: regex

I have text: `"Johnny Alan Walker  Sint Jansstraat 7, 1012 HG Amsterdam +123456789012"`

**Is is possible** to find Lastname and phone? 
Exclude address?
Address regex is this: `"([A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{1,}\s){2}[0-9]{0,4}\,\s{1,}[0-9]{4}\s[A-Z]{2}\s{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}"` (two words from capital, housenumber, comma, postal code and city)

I want result string to be `"Walker +123456789012"`

Comment: Is the name and address always separated with 2 spaces?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ there can be more than 1

Comment: *can* be ***or*** *will* be?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ can benore than 1

Comment: Will there always be 3 names?

Comment: @VladyslavKushney -- Have you had the chance to look at my answer?  It looks like it should handle what you need it to do.

Comment: @VladyslavKushney -- See my answer for an updated ideone example for this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need, and also doesn't assume three names (works without a middle name present), so it's a little more flexible in case you run into entries for people who don't have a middle name:

```
.*?(\w+)\s*(?:[A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{1,}\s){2}[0-9]{0,4}\,\s{1,}[0-9]{4}\s[A-Z]{2}\s{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}\s*(\+\d+)
```

- `.*?(\w+)\s*` - Capture the last word before the whitespace before the address. `.*?` will lazily match anything up to the word preceeding the address, but not capture. `\s*` will match the whitespace between the word and the address.
- `(?:[A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{1,}\s){2}[0-9]{0,4}\,\s{1,}[0-9]{4}\s[A-Z]{2}\s{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}` - your address regex but using a non-capturing group (`?:`)
- `\s*(\+\d+)` - Captures the `+` and following numbers. `\s*` will match the whitespace between the address and the `+`.

I reused your address regex, but made the capture group non-capturing. Then we match the last word before the address (the last name) using `(\w+)`, and the `+` and following numbers after the address using `(\+\d+)`.

Here it is in action: https://regex101.com/r/YGiaJT/1

Answer (score 1):

You could do....

```
\w+\s+\w+\s+(\w+).*(\+\d+)
```

And your capture groups should match up pretty well with what you're trying to match...

Essentially this will "disregard" your first and second "words" (first / middle name) and then disregard EVERYTHING from in between until it finds a + then captures the digits after it.

Live example:  https://regex101.com/r/MjJCSv/1

In theory if your last name and your address will always be separated by more than 1 space you can shorten this a little bit and write it as

```
(\w+)\s{2,}.*(\+\d+)
```

Live example of this functionality:  https://regex101.com/r/vGGB4z/1

Example implementation of the later in java:  http://ideone.com/RExAEO

Comment: I'm being pedantic, but this doesn't capture the `+` from the phone number as per OPs desired output.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Ah, thanks for pointing that out to me, updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: String like this: "Johnny Alan Walker  Sint Jansstraat 7, 1012 HG Amsterdam +123456789012 01-01-1970 jw@example.com azazaza   azazaza James Bob Jameson Oudezijds Achterburgwal 20, 1012 DM Amsterdam +234567890123 02-02-1980 jameson@example.com  azazaza  azazaza    azazaza Jack Glenn Daniels Prins Hendrikkade 1211, 1011 AM Amsterdam +345678901234 03-03-1990 jdaniels@example.com"

Comment: @VladyslavKushney -- If you have a string like that, why not just make an array of strings, splitting on each entry and then loop over it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to capture just the surname and the phone number.

The first part (`(\w+\s){3}`) will capture the 3<sup>rd</sup> occurrence of a word followed by a space.

The second part (`.+?`) will capture everything

The third part (`(\+?\d+)$`) will capture an optional `+` (phone number prefix) and the rest of the phone number, up to the end of the string.

```
(\w+\s){3}.+?(\+?\d+)$
```

- `\1` - The surname
- `\2` - The phone number

https://regex101.com/r/gqu0tt/4

**But**, IF the surname and the address is separated with more than 1 space, then you can use

```
(\w+)\s{2,}.+?(\+?\d+)$
```

- `\1` - The surname
- `\2` - The phone number

https://regex101.com/r/gqu0tt/5

---

<sup>I've [tested these expressions on the Java engine](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), and they give back the correct match</sup>